# I am being given 3 structures and i have to use heaps and enter some data into the members of the structures

Tags: c, struct, printf, malloc, free

How can I access the data stored in qText using the pointer to exam pointer `e`? Here is my current code:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* aText;
    BOOL correct;
}Answer;

typedef struct 
{
    char* qText;
    unsigned int mark;
    Answer answers[MAX_ANSWERS];
}Question;

typedef struct
{
    char* title;
    Question* questions[MAX_QUESTIONS];
}Exam;
```

Comment: You should have got up earlier this morning to do your homework

Comment: e->questions[i]->qText, i am using this to access the qTexta nd doesnt seem to work @EdHeal

Comment: What do you mean "doesnt seem to work"

Comment: its giving me segemntation fault

Comment: Then the problem is in the construction - best using a debugger to explore the datastructure

Comment: i have entered some data into it using strcpy
and then trying to print it in some other function

Comment: @loco post the `strcpy()` part, did you allocate memory for the string with `malloc()`?

Comment: printf("Enter a new ques \n");
  scanf("%s",&dest);
  while ((flushChar = getchar()) != '\n' && flushChar != EOF);
  fflush(stdout);
  q->qText = (char *) malloc(strlen(dest)+1);
  strcpy(q->qText,dest);

Comment: Question* q = (Question*)malloc(sizeof (Question));

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, try this

```
if (e != NULL)
{
    Question *question;
    question = e->questions[i];
    if (question != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", question->qText);
}
```